# Clear a method's body

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In order to handle a -q (quiet) option in my script, I did this:

```
class NoWrite
  def write(*args)
  end
end
$stdout = NoWrite.new if $options[:quiet]
```

It works fine.
However I'm wondering if there isn't a metaprogramming way of making the `write` method moot.

`remove_method` and `undef_method` can't be used because the `write` method has to be defined, I just want to make it do nothing.

Also, `$stderr` can't be impacted.

Comment: you could also overwrite `#method_missing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use instance_eval for this:

```
$stdout.instance_eval{ def write(*args); end } if $options[:quiet]
```

Or you can make an anonymous class:

```
$stdout = Class.new{ def self.write(*args); end } if $options[:quiet]
```

Comment: I like this one better, it's more platform independant

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can redirect stdout to `/dev/null`

```
def stfu
  begin
    orig_stdout = $stdout.clone
    $stdout.reopen File.new('/dev/null', 'w')
    retval = yield
  rescue Exception => e
    $stdout.reopen orig_stdout
    raise e
  ensure
    $stdout.reopen orig_stdout
  end
  retval
end

require 'some_noisy_gem'
stfu do
  some_function_that_generates_a_lot_of_cruft_on_stdout
end
```

Original snippet is at: https://jacob.hoffman-andrews.com/README/index.php/2011/04/14/ruby-function-stfu-temporarily-redirect-noisy-stdout-writes-to-devnull/

Comment: I prefer this way of handling it. It gives `/dev/null` something to do. Normally it sits there doing nothing.

Comment: @theTinMan: Why, is `/dev/null` wreaking havoc on your system out of boredom?